# Updating only the tapped ListTile color in a list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How do I update the color of only the `ListTile` that is tapped?

Whatever I tried, it just changes the color of all tiles when tap.
How can I retrieve the data and change the color?

```
class _DesignState extends State<Design> {
   var status=0;
  var score =0;
 Color getContainerColor() {
    if (status == 0) {
      return Colors.white;
    } else if (status == 1) {
      return Colors.green;
    } else {
      return Colors.red;
    }


  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
    final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);
    final record1=  Firestore.instance.collection('creds').document('123').get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      var s =Record.fromSnapshot(ds);
      score= s.score;
    });

        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(record.name),
          trailing: Text(record.score.toString()),

          onTap: () { record.reference.updateData({'score': FieldValue.increment(score)}),
          setState(){
                status=1;
```

Comment: When on tapped the listile color should remain.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already on the right track, but it looks like you're managing the state of all of your list tile in the same [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).

Instead you'll just need to split them up, so that every of your custom [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) has it's on state. The loading of the data can happen in the parent component of your self build `ListTile`.

---

I'll provide you a short example application. The following example is without firebase, but it should be no problem to apply these changes to your application.

You'd simply have to do the data fetching inside the parent component and pass the `score` parameter of your example to `MyListTile` – just like the title in the example below.

This is runnablbe on it's own, you can simply copy it into a empty Flutter project:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            MyListTile(title: 'First'),
            MyListTile(title: 'Second'),
            MyListTile(title: 'Third'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyListTile({this.title});

  @override
  _MyListTileState createState() => _MyListTileState();
}

class _MyListTileState extends State<MyListTile> {
  int status = 0;

  get tileColor {
    switch(status) {
      case 0: {
        return Colors.white;
      }
      case 1: {
        return Colors.green;
      }
      default: {
        return Colors.red;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: tileColor,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        subtitle: Text('Status: $status'),
        onTap: () => setState(() {
          status++;
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```